# Math in table mixed with text and proper alignment

Tags: tables, math-mode

I have some problems using tabular environment mixed with math formulars, multiple lines and alignment. I have this code:

```
\begin{tabular}[!ht]{p{5cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}}
    \toprule
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    \midrule
        Text with a\\
        linebreak
        &
        \[
            A = B
            = C
        \]
        & Text with wrong vertical alignment \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Which produces this latex

[image: rendered table with math environment and wrong alignment]

As you can see, there are several problems with this:

- Col2 and A = B = C is not aligned horizontal
- A = B = C is not at the top of the cell
- = C should be in the next line (I need multiline equations)
- I can't use `&= C` to align the equal signs when using multiline equations
- "Text with wrong..." is also not at the top of the cell
- I have to specify every single column with its width in cm. Is there a way to only specify one width and let the other columns fit into the left space?
- I have to repeat the `\[` and `\]` for every line. I found sth with predefined commands inside the `{p{5cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}}`, where you can add automatically a math env to the cell. But it hasn't worked

I found several table environments, like threeparttable, table, tabular... I'm a little bit confused which one to use, and I don't know how to achieve the layout I want to have (and I don't know which packages to use). So maybe someone can help me.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you didn't provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so i made some (not entirely correct) assumptions.

first, the `\\` before "linebreak" causes the current line to end.  use `\newline` instead within a paragraph in a table.

second, the `amsmath` `aligned` environment doesn't need to be in a display environment (which will center it).  it works just as well within ordinary math mode.  but since `\\` is required for the line break, the whole thing needs to be hidden in a group, most easily done with `{...}` braces.  and adding a `[t]` option will align it on the top baseline.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[!ht]{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}}
    \toprule
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 \\
    \midrule
        Text with a\newline
        linebreak
        &
        {$\begin{aligned}[t]
            A &= B\\a
              &= C
          \end{aligned}
        $}
        & Text with wrong vertical alignment \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```